# Use webhook to permit users access AWS S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

I want to use AWS S3 for saving files of my users. Users may be permitted to access other's dynamically.
I don't want to use IAM policies (or similar ways) for controlling access of users.
Is it possible for S3 to invoke my API endpoint with user's information and asks for permission?

PS. Users are using credentials that I have gave them.

Comment: It isn't possible to have S3 call your API for authentication.

Comment: Have the users invoke your API endpoint and if they supply the correct credentials then you can send them pre-signed, time-limited URLs for the S3 object(s) of interest.